# Overloading && for `std::variant` breaks an unrelated `std::map`

Tags: c++, gcc

<sup>(This question was originally asked by a different user at [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1285987/215103). I'm reposting it here with minor changes to give it more exposure.)</sup>

Consider this code:

```
#include <map>
#include <variant>

void operator&&(std::variant<int>, std::variant<int>) {}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> vals;
    vals.find(42);
}
```

Clang (with both libstdc++ and libc++) and MSVC compile it without problems.

Hovewer, GCC 11.1 and newer (including trunk) give this: <kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:14,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:14,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:14,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:14,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cmap%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Avoid+operator%26%26(std::variant%3Cint%3E,+std::variant%3Cint%3E)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::map%3Cint,+int%3E+vals%3B%0A++++vals.find(42)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.960835509138384,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:48.31460674157304,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:12,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+gcc+11.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:51.685393258426956,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:55.03916449086162,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/map:60,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::is_invocable<const std::less<int>&, const int&, const int&>':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/type_traits:3001:73:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_invocable_v<const std::less<int>&, const int&, const int&>'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_tree.h:770:8:   required from 'static const _Key& std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_S_key(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type) [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type = const std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, int> >*]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_tree.h:1903:36:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, const _Key&) [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >::iterator; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, int> >*; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_tree.h:2521:36:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const _Key&) [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >::iterator]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_map.h:1170:25:   required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >::iterator; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]'
<source>:9:14:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/type_traits:2942:7: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator&&' (operand types are 'std::true_type' {aka 'std::integral_constant<bool, true>'} and 'std::true_type' {aka 'std::integral_constant<bool, true>'})
 2942 |       static_assert((std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/type_traits:2942:7: note: candidate: 'operator&&(std::integral_constant<bool, true>::value_type {aka bool}, std::integral_constant<bool, true>::value_type {aka bool})' (built-in)
<source>:4:6: note: candidate: 'void operator&&(std::variant<int>, std::variant<int>)'
    4 | void operator &&(std::variant<int>, std::variant<int>) {}
      |      ^~~~~~~~
```

What's going on here?

---

**EDIT:**

Our `operator==` overload should be invisible for name lookup from `<variant>` (except for ADL, which is not involved here), so this is definitely a GCC bug.

@rustyx found [GCC bug #51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577), which looks very similar. But there's more to it, because that bug was introduced in GCC 4.7.0, while the code above only breaks and 11.1 and newer.

Comment: Looks to me that `std::true_type` is implicitly convertible to `bool` and `std::variant<int>`. So the overload introduces an ambiguity for `std::true_type{} && std::true_type{}`.

Comment: While you're allowed to write this operator, I would advise against overloading operators whose operators are strictly built-in and `std` types. Different developers or different libraries might not agree on what that operator is supposed to do. It's easy to end up with multiple definitions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Though this overload should be invisible for name lookup from `<variant>`. See edit.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Using gcc 12+ can compile successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a GCC bug, fixed in GCC 12.